# How Do I Align Divs With Different Heights?

Tags: html, css, alignment, vertical-alignment

I'm having trouble aligning my divs. My divs have no set height so they take the height of how much text is inside.

Here is a photo of what it looks like now.

[image]

Notice the prince post is aligned right and under that post is another post aligned under it. I can't seem to figure out what's going wrong in this.

Here is my html:

```
<div class="row" style="padding:30px 10px 30px 20px; margin:auto;  display:block;">

 <div class="large-12 column large-columnz">
 <a href="post url"><img src=""></a>
 <div class="row column">The Title
 Article Excerpt</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is the css:

```
.large-columnz {  
    max-width:560px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    *display: inline;
 }
```

I am using the [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/css.html) responsive framework to design my site as well as my own incorporated css.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong which causes the last two post to not align.

Answer (score 1):

in the parent div that wraps all the divs ( if you don't have a wrapping div then add 1 ) and then add display: flex; in the parent div style and all the child containers will have the same height..

Comment: That actually wrapped all of them next to each other. Not how I wanted

Comment: can you show me a picture of how it should look like

Comment: Here is what it looked like. http://cdn.ratedrnb.com/2016/05/flex.png  @Dhaval Chheda

Comment: try this CSS <style>
        .row {
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
        }
        .large-columnz {
            flex: 1;
            min-width: 100px;
            margin: 10px;
        }

    </style>

Comment: Found out what was wrong, I needed to clear the float above this section.